# Why Hiberante doesn't have UNION implemented?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I know that Hibernate doesn't have UNION implemented but the question is why? I found that issue is already reported for this and it's very old (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050). Of course union can be replaced with IN clause but it's not the same. Are there any hopes that it will be implemented some day?

Comment: Simply [it is not implemented by them](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Does_HQL_support_UNION_or_INTERSECT)

Comment: As a hint I will create a view containing the UNION then using hibernate to query the view object.